# Reduce fieldNorm consideration at query time

Tags: solr

I would like to lower or eliminate the contribution of the fieldNorm on some searches. I figured that a LocalParam might help, but I cannot find any documentation on it. Is there documentation on how to reduce the consideration for tf, idf, fieldNorm, and coord?

Note that I am specifically looking for a query-time solution. I am not the only client on this index and other than this specific corner-case the index performs well for its purpose.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similarity is defined in the schema.xml and applies to the complete Core.
This cannot be changed per query.
You would need to check rather how to boost the fields.

Other option is :-

Copy to other field with `omitNorms=true` which would disable Length Normalization.
You can switch either the field to be queried on depending upon the requirements.

[Documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Recommended_fields) :-

> omitNorms=true|false
>   This is arguably an advanced option. Set to true to omit the norms
>   associated with this field (this disables length normalization and
>   index-time boosting for the field, and saves some memory). Only
>   full-text fields or fields that need an index-time boost need norms.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that only one field is being searched in, and if any users have single-word texts in this field then Solr pushes those results to the top, even though they are the most useless texts possible (think image descriptions). However, we run into this issue only on a very specific subset of posts, and I don't want to change the scoring for other posts. I suppose that I could add a second non-stored field of duplicate content with a different similarity definition. Does that sound feasible?

Comment: Thanks Jayendra. `omitNorms` is also a configuration option, not something that I can change at query time. I'll leave the question open to see if anybody can concoct a workaround, and if not then I'll select your answer. Thank you!

Comment: yup you would need to update the schema once and then can handle it at query time.